# How to make jquery scroll effect like tumblr?

Tags: jquery

As you can see in this link: https://www.tumblr.com/explore/text
When we click and drag hashtags to left and right too much, they will automatically move back to original position.

Now I can make my links, which means <a> elements, moved to left and right but they can't be taken back to their original position if I drag too much. My work is here: https://codepen.io/victorcruzte/pen/oxMYJw

HTML:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="children">
      <a href="#">abcdefg</a>
      <a href="#">abcdefg</a>
      <a href="#">abcdefg</a>
      <a href="#">abcdefg</a>
      <a href="#">abcdefg</a>
      <a href="#">abcdefg</a>
      <a href="#">abcdefg</a>
      <a href="#">abcdefg</a>
    </div>

  </div>
```

CSS:

```
.parent {
  margin: 200px auto;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
.children {
  float: left;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

JS:

```
var x1, x2 = 0, x3;
var click = false;
var temp = 0, temp2, temp3 = 0;

function draga() {
  $('.children a').click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
    });

  $('.children').mousedown(function(e) {
    click = true;
    x1 = e.pageX;
  });

  $(document).mouseup(function() {
    click = false;
  });

  $('.children').mousemove(function(e) {
    if (click === false) return;
    e.stopPropagation();
    (temp3 != x1) ? (temp2 = 0) : (temp2 = x2);
    temp3 = x1;
    x2 = e.pageX;
    (temp2 === 0) ? x3 = (x2 - x1) : x3 = (x2 - temp2);
    temp += x3;
    $(this).css('background-color', 'pink');
    $(this).css('transform', 'translate('+ temp + 'px, 0px');
  });
};


$(window).load(function() {
  draga();
});
```

I'm new to jquery, so hope you can help me. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I think I solved your problem and hope it will help. 
Please see below code and snippet:

What your were missing is the check when the children elements get out och the perent element.

```js
var xStart = 0;
var xStop = 0;
var xDelta = 0;

function draga() {
  $('.children').find('a').attr('onmousedown', 'return false')

  $('.children a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  });

  $('.children').mousedown(function(e) {
    xStart = e.pageX;

    $(document).mousemove(function(e) {
      xDelta = parseInt((e.pageX + xStop) - xStart);
      $('.children').css('transform', 'translate(' + xDelta + 'px, 0)');
    })
  });

  $(document).mouseup(function(e) {
    if (xDelta > 185) {
   
      $({ Counter: xDelta }).animate({ Counter: 0 }, {
     duration: 500,
     step: function () {
       $('.children').css('transform', 'translate('+ this.Counter +'px, 0)');
     }
   });
      xDelta = 0;
    } else if (xDelta < -($('.children').width() - 15)) {
      xDelta += Math.abs($('.children').width() - Math.abs(xDelta)) + 200;
      
      $({ Counter: -$('.children').width() }).animate({ Counter: xDelta }, {
     duration: 500,
     step: function () {
       $('.children').css('transform', 'translate('+ this.Counter +'px, 0)');
     }
   });
    }

    xStop = xDelta;
    $(document).off("mousemove");
  })
}

$(window).load(function() {
  draga();
});
```

```css
.parent {
  margin: 50px auto;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.children {
  float: left;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="parent">
  <div class="children">
    <a href="#">abcdefg</a>
    <a href="#">abcdefg</a>
    <a href="#">abcdefg</a>
    <a href="#">abcdefg</a>
    <a href="#">abcdefg</a>
    <a href="#">abcdefg</a>
    <a href="#">abcdefg</a>
    <a href="#">abcdefg</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! But it's really hard to understand, however:D

Comment: The whole sulu ruin is based on mathematics and the only thing you forgot was to check when the end of div passes the container. Then I have also fixed so there is a smooth draging by removing the copy option and the added some animation for the rebounds effect when the div is bounding back after leaving the container. Hope this helps.